# Function whose inverse is also its derivative?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functional-equations

What are some good examples of a function  $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ where its derivative is equal to its inverse? I attempted to find a monomial that satisfied it by starting with $f(x) = ax^b$ and showing that $f^{-1}(x) = f'(x) \implies b-1=\frac{1}{b} \implies b=\phi$ and got
$$f(x) = \frac{x^\phi}{\sqrt[\phi]{\phi}}$$
Which seems to work according to WolframAlpha, but I'm having trouble double-checking it. Any other ideas?

Comment: The first assertion is wrong. The functions equal to their derivative are the functions $x\mapsto c\mathrm e^x$, for some $c$.

Comment: @did: Actually it's not c times e to the power of x. It's c times e to the power of cx

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan No.

Comment: $$(ce^{cx})'=c^2e^{cx}\neq ce^{cx}\Longrightarrow$$ did is right.

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan No. $y^{\prime}-y=0\Rightarrow y^{\prime}e^{-x}-ye^{-x}=0\Rightarrow (ye^{-x})^{\prime}=0\Rightarrow ye^{-x}=c\Rightarrow y=ce^{x}$

Comment: @did: OK, OK! You're right :)

Comment: Yes, made a stupid mistake there, silly me.

Comment: The question you are really asking is to determine the functions whose derivative is the inverse of that function, apart from the two you found. This question is interesting.

Comment: Hmmmm... *(are there more?)*... **YES THERE ARE** (see supra).

Comment: Ok, i think I got that there are infinitely many of those :)

Comment: This question appeared some time ago at mathoverflow. There you can find some  solutions of the problem which are completely different from the above. See here:  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/34052/function-satisfying-f-1-f/34095#34095

Comment: @Christian Blatter Thanks, that place answers OK. I guess the question is more or less answered :) Thanks all.

Comment: I suppose it's worth pointing out that the given solution is a function $f:[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$, and the other solution to the quadratic for $b$ also yields a solution $f:(-\infty,0)\to(-\infty,0)$, so if you paste the solutions together, you get a solution $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ as you wanted.

Comment: Hey any feedback concerning my answer/idea would be nice...

Comment: @MarioCarneiro: I don't think that's correct.  The other $b$ is negative, but $x^b$ would be defined for $x>0$.  Even if defined on $(-\infty,0)$, there would be no way to paste them together in a way that gives a solution to this problem.

Comment: Actually for the negative $b$ I don't know how you would define $\sqrt[b]{b}$.

Comment: @JonasMeyer Just start from $a(-x)^b$ instead. (I agree that the solutions cannot be pasted together consistently though.)

Comment: @Mario: Oh, I didn't see how to solve that without raising negative numbers to irrational powers, which requires complex numbers.  E.g., what is $\sqrt[b]{b}$ when $b<0$ and $b$ is irrational?  I guess it becomes $a=-(-b)^{-1/b}$?  Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an alternative: You can use 
$$
        f^{-1}(x)=\int\frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(x))}\,dx + c. \tag{1}
$$
from ["Inverse functions and differentiation"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_functions_and_differentiation#Additional_properties).

Set $f^{-1}(x)=f'(x)$ and for simplicity take the derivative of $(1)$. You get 
$$
f''(x)=\frac1{f'(f'(x))}.
$$
Now put in $f(x)=\phi^{-\frac1\phi}x^\phi$. Using $\phi-1=\frac1\phi$, you'll get
$$
f'(x)=\phi^{2-\phi}x^{\phi-1}\\
f''(x)=\phi^{1-\phi}x^{\phi-2}
$$
Now put it all together and use $\phi^2=\phi+1$:
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
f''(x)&=&\frac1{f'(f'(x))}\\
\phi^{1-\phi}x^{\phi-2}&=&\left(\phi^{2-\phi}\left(\phi^{2-\phi} 
x^{\phi-1}\right)^{\phi-1}\right)^{-1}\\
&=&\left(\phi^{2-\phi}\left(\phi^{3\phi-2-\phi^2}x^{\phi^2-2\phi+1}\right)\right)^{-1}\\
&=&\left(\phi^{2\phi-\phi-1}x^{\phi+1-2\phi+1}\right)^{-1}\\
&=&\left(\phi^{\phi-1}x^{-\phi+2}\right)^{-1}\\
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Answer (score 5):

What you have given is only a function from $(0,\infty)$ to $(0,\infty)$, not $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$.  See [Function satisfying $f^{-1} =f'$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34052/function-satisfying-f-1-f/34095#34095) on MathOverflow for some other ideas and more thorough analysis with this restriction to positive reals.

For the domain $\mathbb R$, no solution exists.  A continuous injective $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ must be monotone, which implies that its derivative cannot change sign, but $f^{-1}$ would include both positive and negative numbers in its range.

---

Here's what it looks like in Desmos if you extend your answer following [Mario Carneiro's advice in a comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/735695/function-whose-inverse-is-also-its-derivative#comment1535072_735695) (which I didn't understand at first):

[image]

Piecing these functions together gives an invertible map from $\mathbb R$ onto $\mathbb R$ such that $f'(x) = f^{-1}(x)$  when $f'(x)$  exists, and $f'(0)$ doesn't exist, but the right-hand derivative $\lim\limits_{h\to 0+}\dfrac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}$ exists and equals $0=f^{-1}(0)$.   Considering that a differentiable solution is impossible, this is pretty good.

Answer (score 3):

When you set $f^{-1}(x)=f'(x)$ these functions have the property that
$$
        f^{-1}(x)=\int\frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(x))}\,dx + c. \tag{1}
$$
from ["Inverse functions and differentiation"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_functions_and_differentiation#Additional_properties).

Comment: see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/773220/19341) for a worked out example...

Answer (score -1):

Start with $\dot{y}=y^{-1}$  Apply Lie Group $G(x,y)=(\lambda x,\lambda^\beta y)\lambda_o=1$
Stabilizers for this group include $\mu=\frac{y}{x^\frac{1}{2}}$ and $\nu=x^{\frac{1}{2}}\dot{y}$.  Multiplying the DEQ by $x^{\frac{1}{2}}$ we have $x^{\frac{1}{2}}\dot{y}=\bigg(\frac{x^{\frac{1}{2}}}{y}\bigg)$ which makes our DEQ, in stabilizer form, $\nu=\mu^{-1}$.  Since $$x\frac{d\mu}{dx}=\nu -\beta\mu = \mu^{-1} -\frac{1}{2}\mu$$ $$\frac{d\mu}{\mu^{-1}-\frac{1}{2}\mu}=\frac{dx}{x}$$ Integrating this gives $$-ln(\mu^2-2)=lnx+lnC$$ Substituting for $\mu$ and rearranging arrives at the solution: $$y=\sqrt{2x+C}$$

Comment: Or more simply: $y' = \dfrac 1 y \Rightarrow \int y \,dy = \int dx \Rightarrow \dfrac{y^2}{2} = x + c \Rightarrow y = \sqrt{2x + C}$. The OP is not asking for a function whose derivative is its *reciprocal*, though. "Inverse" here means "the inverse function".