# When derivative of a function is its inverse function and vice-versa

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find $ f(x)$ if

$$ f'(x)= f^{-1} (x)$$

where $f^{-1} (x)$ is inverse function of $f(x)$.

Do they form a dual set, that is whether also

$(f^{-1})'(x) = f(x)$

when $f(x)$ is  inverse  function of $f^{-1} (x)$.

Comment: Please use a more clear notation. Is $fi$ the inverse function ($f^{-1}$), as it says in the title, or the derivative of the inverse ($\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}f^{-1}$), as it says in the body?

Comment: Duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/735695/function-whose-inverse-is-also-its-derivative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, differentiating
$$
x = f(f^{-1}(x))
$$
we get
$$
1 = f'(f^{-1}(x)) \, (f^{-1})'(x) \quad (*)
$$

We have the ODE
$$
f'(x) = f^{-1}(x)
$$
so $(*)$ turns into
$$
1 = f'(f'(x)) \, f''(x) \iff \\
f''(x) = \frac{1}{f'(f'(x))} \quad (**)
$$
Trying the Ansatz
$$
f(x) = a \, x^b
$$
one gets
$$
f'(x) = ab \, x^{b - 1} \\
f''(x) = a b(b-1) \, x^{b-2}
$$
and
$$
f'(f'(x)) = ab(ab\,x^{b-1})^{b-1} = (ab)^b x^{(b-1)^2} \\
1/f'(f'(x)) = (ab)^{-b}x^{-(b-1)^2}
$$
Using $(**)$ and comparison of the powers gives the system
$$
ab(b-1) = (ab)^{-b} \\
b - 2 = -(b-1)^2
$$
The second equation turns into
$$
b^2 - b - 1 = 0
$$
which is the quadratic equation, which has the [golden ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio) as positive solution:
$$
b = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} = \phi
$$ 
The first equation then turns
$$
a(b^2 - b) = a = a^{-b} b^{-b} \iff \\
a^{b+1} = a^{b^2} = b^{-b} \iff \\
a = b^{-b/b^2} = b^{-1/b}
$$
This gives the solution
$$
f(x) = \phi^{-1/\phi} \, x^{\phi}
$$
which was earlier given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/773220/86776) by draks and indeed the plot below, which features $f$ (in red) and $f'$ (in blue) shows that $f'$ is the reflection of $f$ at $\DeclareMathOperator{id}{id}\id$ (green line), or $f'$ is $f^{-1}$.

[image: derivative is inverse]

Answer (score 0):

If $(f^{-1})'(x)=f(x)$ as well, then $f(x)=f''(x)$ and $f(x)=ae^x+be^{-x}$.