# Functions satsify $f'=f^{-1}$ with $f^{-1}$ is compostional inverse of$ f$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, inverse-function, formal-power-series, lagrange-inversion

let $f$ be a function such that :$f:\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ and $f^{-1}$ is the compositional inverse of $f$, I seek for the analyticity of $f$ at $0$, then my question here is :

> > **Question:**
> >     Are there functions satisfy:$f'=f^{-1}$ with  $f^{-1}$  is compostional inverse of  $f$ ?

Comment: related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/735695/function-whose-inverse-is-also-its-derivative/773220

Comment: Have you tried the problem for real values? You could even try it on the integer lattice replacing derivative with a tangent lien.

Comment: @Andre ,I don't asked about multiplicative inverse but about compositional inverse when does coincide with it's derivative ?

Comment: @zeraouliarafik Why do you think this question was about multiplicative inverse?

Comment: @martin: The confusion might be based on one of the two answers being based on multiplicative inverse.  The other answer there doesn't answer this question in part because this one has complex domain (I don't know if it answers the other question either).

Comment: This is not a duplicate of that question, as this one says $f:\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$, looking for analyticity at $0$.  Although no one really answered for $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ either, an answer for $(0,\infty)\to (0,\infty)$ appears and is not applicable here.  Even if ultimately they have the same answer (one not existing), different methods would be used to show it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Such a function appears to not exist.  If $f^{-1}$ exists, then $f^{-1}(f(0))=0$. If $f^{-1}=f'$, then  $f'(f(0))=0$, which implies that $f$ is not invertible in a neighborhood of $f(0)$.

Answer (score 1):

If
$f'=f^{-1}$
and $f(x) = ax^b$,
then
$f'(x) = ab x^{b-1}$
and
$f^{(-1)}(x)
=(x/a)^{1/b}
$
so
$(x/a)^{1/b}
=ab x^{b-1}
$.
If $b \ne 0$,
then,
raising to the $b$ power,
$x/a
=(ab)^b x^{b(b-1)}
$
or
$a^{-b-1}b^{-b}
= x^{b(b-1)-1}
$.

For the right side
to be constant,
we must have
$0
=b(b-1)-1
=b^2-b-1
$
so
$b
=\dfrac{1\pm \sqrt{1+4}}{2}
=\dfrac{1\pm \sqrt{5}}{2}
$
and
$a^{-b-1}b^{-b}
= 1
$
or
$a^{-b-1}
= b^b
$
or,
since
$b+1 = b^2$,
$a
=b^{\frac{b}{-b-1}}
=b^{\frac{b}{-b^2}}
=b^{\frac{-1}{b}}
$.

Comment: And a branch of $z^b$ can be defined on some open subset of $\mathbb C$, but not one containing $0$.  This answer would work for the alternative domain and range $(0,\infty)$ taking the positive $b$.

Comment: My ignoring this shows my ignorance of much of complex function theory.

Comment: There is linked post with real domain, with this given as an example (although it still is restricted to positive reals, and no solution with domain containing a neighborhood of $0$ exists).  Also, $\frac12(1-\sqrt 5)$ doesn't seem to work for the real case, as $b^{-1/b}$ wouldn't be real.